# webEngine.executeScript(); Throwing Exception

Tags: javascript, exception, javafx

I'm writing a JavaFX App, which Interacts with the JavaScript, Using WebView and WebEngine (.executeScript() Method).

Here, I have this part of code from Medow.java, which loads map.html(Contains JavaScript Code), And This Code Works Pretty well:

```
add_button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent ea5) {


            //  webEngine.executeScript("document.fun();");  // For Drawing Shapes
            if (add == false) {

                webEngine.executeScript("document.fun();");  // For Drawing Shapes
                add = true;
            }
//            }
            else {
                webEngine.executeScript("document.reSet();"); // To remove Drawing Shapes
                add = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

In Here

> webEngine.executeScript();

Is Invoking Appropriate JavaScript function's

But Now, I want my Java Code to Invoke Some JS function, when the Program Starts, So I'm directly writing :

```
webEngine.executeScript("document.draw();");
```

right Under/after the code, which loads the map.html file.

So, now as Both of the
     `webEngine.execute("document.fun();");` and `webEngine.executeScript("document.draw();");` are nearly similar, I cannot Understand what Difference does, it makes to be inside the `<button>.setOnAction` block and to be outside it, Because both WebEngine and webView are declared as Global Variables.

cannot invoke document.draw() function using HTML's onLoad options, because i need to pass some Values To function draw from java.

The Exception Generated is :

```
   netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.draw()')
```

how can i make this work? thank you

While Continuously trying to figure out whats the cause, I Discovered That the HTMLDocument Object, created using `webEngine.load()`, is for some reason visible only inside the handle method, And nowhere else, even though its been defined outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that you want to call a JavaScript function before the content is loaded completely. Therefore the function `draw` is not defined. So the only way is to wait until the page is loaded. There are two ways that might prove useful:
Add a changelistener on the state and execute the JavaScript once the loading has succeeded:
    String htmlURL = ...
    webView.getEngine().load(htmlURL);

```
webView.getEngine().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State t, Worker.State t1) {
        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            // this will be run as soon as WebView is initialized.
            webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.draw()");               
        }
    }
});
```

The other way is more of a solution within JavaScript. You first have to register a bridge between Java and your html page (has to be done in the `SUCCEEDED` state change as well, see [WebView callback from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541933/webview-callback-from-javascript)):

```
JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("app", this);
```

Now this JavaObject is referenced in your JavaScript. Let's say that you have a method on the class that is of the above type of `this`:

```
public void executeOnPageLoaded() {
  ...
}
```

Then you can call this method from Javascript. If you are using jQuery it could look like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    app.executeOnPageLoaded();
});
```

This second approach is more complex but in the long run may give you more flexibility.

When you start working with JavaScript in the WebView is is a good idea to have Firebug lite in there as well, so investigate what is happening but mainly to have a means to seed the console output of JavaScript. See [Java FX application onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073837/java-fx-application-onload-event)